# Can this be done using Facebook Connect?

Tags: c#, facebook

Here is the sequence of events I would like to see happen:

1. Visitor shows up to my site and clicks the connect button
2. Visitor authorizes the connection by logging into their facebook account
3. My site records their authorization
4. My site posts to their wall "Sally just joined http://foo.com. A website about foo."
5. Much later, my site can post other updates to the users wall using the stored authorization from step 3. Sally doesn't have to be actively on my site at the time this post to their wall happens.

I'm using C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the Facebook Graph API and it does everything. So much nicer than the old API

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. In fact, they've pulled all old documentation for Facebook Connect. So even if it was possible, it's no longer the "supported" way to do it.